# Cookie set in wordpress is being deleted after being set in specific page

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

I am trying to set a cookie in wordpress using an hook in functions.php, but the cookie values come out empty. How can I set the cookie getting the values from the URL ($_GET)?

(Edit) I only need this cookie to be set at an specific page, so I wrapped it on an if statement. The cookie is now set correctly. But when I move to another page and try to get the cookie it's not set anymore! Any Ideas why this could be happening?

(Edit 2) I fixed this by setting the cookie path to "/".

```
function set_cookie(){
if(is_page('hotel')){
  $destinationType = 'city'; //'city';
  $destinationCode = $_GET["dcode"]; //'lon';
  $checkinDate = $_GET["date_in"]; //date('2013-08-05'); // '2006-05-10';
  $checkoutDate = $_GET["date_out"];
  $date1 = strtotime($checkinDate);
  $date2 = strtotime($checkoutDate);
  $datediff = $date2 - $date1;
  $duration = floor($datediff / (60 * 60 * 24));

  //Create Search Object
  $search = array();
  $search[0] = $destinationType;
  $search[1] = $destinationCode;
  $search[2] = $checkinDate;
  $search[3] = $checkoutDate;
  $search[4] = $duration;
  //Create Rooms Object
  $packages = array();
  $npack = intval($_GET['numpack']);
  for ($j = 0; $j < $npack; $j++) {
      $packages[$j][0] = $_GET['rtype' . ($j + 1)];
      $packages[$j][1] = 1; //$_GET['nroom' . ($j + 1)];
      $packages[$j][2] = $_GET['cot' . ($j + 1)];
      if ($packages[$j][2] == null) {
          $packages[$j][2] = '0';
      }
      for ($k = 0; $k < intval($_GET['children' . ($j + 1)]); $k++) {
          $packages[$j][3][$k] = $_GET['achild' . ($j + 1) . '_' . ($k + 1)];
      }
  }

  //Complete Search Object to cookie
  $searchObject = array($search, $packages);
  setcookie('searchobject', json_encode($searchObject), time() + 3600, "/");
  }

  }

add_action('get_header', 'set_cookie');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the cookie is there, but it's empty, I suggest checking if `json_encode()` does it's job. It returns `null` whenever it encounters some character not of its liking. A nice way to check is [`json_last_error()`](https://www.php.net/function.json_last_error), which you have to call somewhere after `json_encode()`.

You may do a full step-by-step checking on your problem:

1. can I set the cookie with a simple constant string
2. does my `$searchObject` contains what I want
3. does `json_encode()` properly produces json data

In my answer I assumed the first two are ok.

Comment: When I use this code directly on a php file the cookie is created correctly, the problem is that I cannot do this on the page template because if I generate the cookie above the `get_header()` function the site loads without the style.css breaking it.

Comment: That's why you are adding it to the get_header hook. But you can test, if your function is actually called, and if it is, then it should work.

Comment: I am able to set the cookie now, but I only need to set this cookie on a certain page, so I am using an if inside my function `if(is_page('hotel')){//Set cookies}` and the cookie is being set properly. But when I move to another page the cookie is deleted! Any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: I fixed this setting the cookie path to "/" thanks for the help.

Comment: I assume you set the cookie (by default) to the actual path, and it wasn't available if you changed the path when going to another page. Glad you made it!